# HTML5 - write and read a 2d array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a larger form I have data that is a 2D array. Currently it is hard coded (for ease of development) but eventually it will be stored in local storage and any changes will get saved.  I am using input for displaying the data, and allowing changes to be made.

The context is a role playing game that my son is designing and would like to speed up calculations.
A character has various pieces of armor that also gives them additional skills. Below is an excerpt that gives a subset of what needs to be displayed:

```
 Stats: [{ Component: "Head", Armor: 10, Evasion: 0, HP: 20, MP: 10 },
         { Component: "Chest", Armor: 20, Evasion: 10, HP: 0, MP: 0 },
         { Component: "Arms", Armor: 20, Evasion: 5, HP: 0, MP: 0 },
         { Component: "Hands", Armor: 10, Evasion: 20, HP: 5, MP: 0},
         { Component: "Legs", Armor: 15, Evasion: 0, HP: 0, MP: 0},
         { Component: "Feet", Armor: 10, Evasion: 0, HP: 0, MP: 0 }]
```

It gets displayed on the form as:

```
         Head Chest Arms Hands Legs Feet
Armor     10    20   20    10   15   10
Evasion    0    10    5    20    0    0
HP        20     0    0     5    0    0
MP        10     0    0     0    0    0
```

For displaying simple ratings like Strength and Agility I've done it with the following HTML:

```
<label class="lab" for="strengthID">Strength:</label>
<input class="inp" type="number" id="strengthID" step="any">

<label class="lab" for="agilityID">Agility:</label>
<input class="inp" type="number" id="agilityID" step="any">
```

Note: the classes "lab" and "inp" set the width of the label and input tags.

The following is an excerpt of the javascript I use to display a desired character's data:

```
var strength;
var agility;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    people = [];
    people[0] = {  // here is where I provide the data during development
        Name: "Strider", Hp: 300, Strength: 30, Agility: 20, ... ,
         Stats: [{Component: "Head", Armor: 10,  ... ]
    people[1] = { ...

    strength = document.getElementById("strengthID");
    agility = document.getElementById("agilityID");
    ...
    assignPeople(0);  // to initialize the form with the first person's data.
}

function assignPeople(indx) {

    str.value = people[indx].Strength;
    agility.value = people[indx].Agility;
    ...
}
```

What I do not know how to do is to nicely display the array of stats. Sure, I could laboriously code each pairing of the matrix like:

```
<input class="inp" type="number" id="Armor_Head_ID" step="any">
<input class="inp" type="number" id="Armor_Chest_ID" step="any">
...
```

but that leads to a ton of variables.
I've Googled for answers but probably did not use the right search terms.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make a table?

Comment: @Blender - I am trying to avoid using tables, though in this case it is for data rather than layout. I'd still like to know how to do it without a table.

Comment: What's wrong with tables? You have tabular data, so put it in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a "real" table, you could work with a CSS based table. You create a set of divs, with classes like the ones listed below, and the result is something that looks like a table (which I think would be fine in this case), but you could modify the layout 
completly via CSS. Such a CSS table is not working in IE below 8.

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;
}

.th,.td {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:2px 5px;
}

.th {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tr .td:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100px;
}

.td input {
    width:80px;
}
```

The way I would generate the HTML code for something like this is a bit more dynamic than your approach. Instead of having all the fields
in HTML, I would generate the complete section via javascript.

```
function assignPeople( indx ) {
  var _container = document.getElementById('PersonInfo'),
      _person = people[indx],
      _out = [],
      _keys = [],
      _labels = [];
    for(attrs in _person) {
        _out.push('<div class="row">');
        switch(attrs) {
            // from your example code snippet, you might have more switch cases here, depending
            // on the different field types of your person data.
            case 'Name':
                _out.push('<label class="lab" for="'+attrs + indx+'">'+attrs+':</label>');
                _out.push('<input class="inp" type="text" id="'+attrs + indx+'" value="'+_person[attrs]+'">');
                break;
            case 'Stats':
                 // the nested array...
                 _out.push('<h3>Stats</h3>');
                 for(var i=0, l = _person[attrs].length; i < l; i++) {
                    _keys.push(_person[attrs][i].Component);
                    for( a in _person[attrs][i]) {
                        if(a!='Component' && i==0) {
                            _labels.push(a);
                        }
                    }
                 }
                 _out.push('<div class="tabe">');
                 _out.push('<div class="tr"><div class="th">&nbsp;</div>');

                 for(var i=0, l = _keys.length; i < l; i++) {
                    _out.push('<div class="th">'+_keys[i]+'</div>');
                 }
                 _out.push('</div>');
                 for(var i=0, l = _labels.length; i < l; i++) {
                    _out.push('<div class="tr">');
                    _out.push('<div class="td">'+_labels[i]+'</div>');
                    for(var j=0, k = _person[attrs].length; j < k; j++) {
                        _out.push('<div class="td"><input class="inp" type="number" id="'+attrs + i+ '_' + j +'" step="any" value="'+_person[attrs][j][_labels[i]]+'"></div>');
                    }
                    _out.push('</div>');
                 }
                 _out.push('</div>');
                break;
            default:
                _out.push('<label class="lab" for="'+attrs + indx+'">'+attrs+':</label>');
                _out.push('<input class="inp" type="number" id="'+attrs + indx+'" step="any" value="'+_person[attrs]+'">');
        }
         _out.push('</div>');
    }
    _container.innerHTML = _out.join('');
}
```

You'll find a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/EBGTt/).

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. It is exactly what I need. It also serves as great learning tool to expand my knowledge. I appreciate all the effort that you put in to providing this solution!